# How to add/remove html data in a span using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently doing a simple online bus seat booking system and i am stuck with one feature that whenever user selects more than one bus seat,corresponding seat number should be shown in a **span** or **div** separated by comma and whenever the user unselect the seat(by clicking selected seat again) that seat number must be removed.

I did the first part,ie adding seat number to the span but have no idea how to remove the unselected seat number.Also how to separate seat number by comma.My code is

```js
function bookSeat(seat) {
        var src = $("#" + seat).attr('src');
//        alert(src);
        if (src === 'images/availableSeat.gif') {
            $("#" + seat).attr('src', 'images/selectedSeat.gif');
            if ($('#seats').is(':empty')) {
                $("#seats").append(seat);
            } else {
                $("#seats").append(" , "+seat);
            }

        }
        else if (src === 'images/selectedSeat.gif') {
            $("#" + seat).attr('src', 'images/availableSeat.gif');
           // code to remove the unselected seat number
        }
    }
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: what should .append(seat) expect to do?

Comment: to show the selected seat number in a span

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your string into a array and remove the seat value, join the array and append it to the seat div
TRy:

```
  function remove(seat) {
    var array = $("#seats").html().split(",");
    $.each(array,function(i,v){
       if (v == seat) {
            array.splice(i,1);
         }
    });
    return array.join();
    }
data = remove('seat2');
 $("#seats").append(data);
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/c5us7u23/